# Prevent spoken messages from being replayed in a chat application.

Tags: c#

I am making a LAN chat application with spoken messages using C#. I'm using SAPI 5.1, and I have encountered problem with speaking the messages. If I write the message "HI" his computer will receive the message and speak the word "HI" which is OK, but if I write a new message for example "HELLO" his computer will repeat speaking the first message "HI" and then speak the word "HELLO".

The old message "HI" should not be repeated again, and it should say the new message "HELLO".

Here is my code:

```
private void rtbConversation_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    speech.Rate = speechRate;
    speech.Speak(rtbConversation.Text, SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync);

    speech.Voice = speech.GetVoices(string.Empty, 
                          string.Empty).Item(combo1.SelectedIndex); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you are running this code when the `TextChanged` event of a `RichTextBox` is invoked. Presumably the `RichTextBox` *accumulates* the messages. Given that you are then passing the `Text` property of the `RichTextBox` to the speech API, it logically follows that *all* messages received so far will be spoken, including any which have spoken before.

Instead of invoking your code each time the text of the rich text box changes, trying using the underlying event which *causes* the text of the rich text box to change. E.g. do you have some kind of listener which exposes a something like a `MessageReceived` event? Such an event should only contain the text of the received message. You could then pass this to the speech API.

If it turns out that the *only* way you can monitor the messages is to handle the `RichTextBox.TextChanged` event, then you will have to have some of way of comparing the new text to the previous text and only speaking what has been added.

Incidentally, it looks as though your `speech.Speak()` call and `speech.Voice` assignment are in the wrong order. I would guess that you should be setting the `Voice` property *before* calling the `Speak()` method. If it works as it is, then I guess this is because you are calling the `Speak()` method with an asynchronous flag and then `Voice` is being set so quickly afterwards that it just happens to work as desired *most* times it is run.

Comment: Hello Adam Ralph can you give a sample code of your answer? please